# Import from parallel folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I can't figure out the way to import from a parallel folder.

Importing from the same directory works fine:

```
project_folder
  -subfolder1
    -my_prog.py
    -credentials.py
```

credentials.py contains

```
api_key = "supersecretapikey"
```

and my_prog.py contains

```
import credentials
```

This works fine when I run `$ python my_prog.py`.

However, I want to move credentials to another subfolder, like so:

```
project_folder
  -subfolder1
    -my_prog.py
  -subfolder2
    -credentials.py
```

I can't get the import to work in this setup. I have tried the obvious thing, which to me is:

```
from ..subfolder2 import credentials
```

This results in the error

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

which I don't understand.

I've tried placing `__init__.py` files in project_folder, subfolder1 and subfolder2, which seems to make no difference.

I prefer not to use environment variables as need to run this on a remote server.

I'm using Python 3.12.2

Comment: For the record, even if axandce gave the correct answer below, I finally ended up using python-dotenv instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the python script inside the same location as a file with a relative import like `..otherModule` won't work.  You can't access files in parent directories (or their children) with relative imports from the location of running the script.  Using relative imports in your code will assume the base directory is where you're running the script from, not where the file itself is located.

A solution for you is to navigate to `project_folder` and run the script there (using "python -m subfolder1.myprog"). Also, in `my_prog.py` change `..subfolder2` to `subfolder2`. By being in `project_folder`, a relative import of `subfolder2` will work in the way you anticipate.  Generally, absolute imports are "better" as they remove this confusion.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. If I'm in project_folder and launch "python subfolder1/my_prog.py" which has the line "from subfolder2 import credentials" I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subfolder2'

Comment: Or do you mean also move myprog.py one level up from subfolder1  to project_folder? That would defeat the purpose of having the different parts of the project in different subfolders.

Comment: Oh, I think what you mean is I'm in the parent folder and run the script like this "python -m subfolder1.myprog"?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, I am in fact using (and usually use) the `python -m subfolder1.myprog` command option.

Comment: @axandce you shouldn't be navigating relying on being in a particular working directory or manually fiddling with `sys.path`, instead, you should be properly packaging your project then `pip install` the project, perhaps in editable mode

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `from A import B` is used to import a component (submodule, function, variable...) `B` from the module `A`. This is rather independent of and not related to any directory structure or paths, which is the problem you are concerned with.

The places where the Python interpreter looks for modules to import are listed in the system variable `sys.path` (which is a list of strings). You can add the directory from where you want to import your own modules using the standard `list.append()` method ([cf. sys.path documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/Sebastian/Dropbox/project_folder/subfolder2')
import credentials   # reads file cedentials.py in subfolder2
```

Note the use of "/" also on Windows, or use `r'c:\Users\...'` to avoid that \ is considered as escape character, or use `"c:\\Users\\..."`.

The above elementary example is of course an oversimplification, just to illustrate how/where the system searches for files to import. You would certainly want to avoid to use a hard-wired absolute system path. So you would rather poroceed along the following lines to get the path to the parent "project_folder" and then the "sister" subfolder:

```
import os
myfolder = os.getcwd()  # typically, "C:\\...\\project_folder\\subfolder1"
project_folder = os.path.dirname(myfolder)  # should be "C:\\...\\project_folder"
sys.path.append( project_folder + "\\subfolder2" )
import credentials
```

Also, instead of `os.getcwd()` you might prefer using the `__file__` variable, which gives you the location of the file which contains this code, as opposed to the location (and/or current working directory) of the main program which possibly includes this, in turn, as a (sub)module.

Also, you might want to insert the new location at the beginning of the `sys.path` list, as to look there first, and also possibly remove it once the import is done.

PS: The above answers the question "how to import from parallel folder". To fetch credentials or other data, `import` might not be the best nor even an adequate choice: you should probbly rather search "how to read in a data file".

Comment: Appreciate your answer, @Max! However, eventually this script will be running on a server and I'm not sure I can set the system variables there. Hence my goal to avoid  environment variables.

Comment: this is *not* the way you should deal witht his

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Sebastian you do not set "system" variables as in "property of the OS", but as in "default value given to you through the sys module for *your* process". Yes, this code also works on servers, e.g., if you run your script on pythonanywhere. Anyway, the work hypothesis is that you want to access. The "import" statement works that way -- this is the official way to tell it where to look, there is no other way to "prefix a path" to the module name.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please be somewhat more constructive. And consider https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path where the official doc says "A program is free to modify this list for its own purposes. Only strings should be added to sys.path; all other data types are ignored during import."

Comment: Also, the question was "how to import...", and I wanted to help with that. Of course, reading in credentials or other data should in general not be done using `import`. I added a "PS" to clarify that.

Comment: You are allowed to modify it. You almost  certainly shouldn't, and instead of relying on hacks, you should package your projects so that they can be installed with pip (perhaps in editable mode) and can be imported without fiddling with the path.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : but the question that was asked here was "how to import from parallel folder", now "how to package your projects" ...

Comment: Yeah, and the answer to that is to *package your project and pip install it*. Look, you think this is a reasonable practice. I don't. I dont think there is much left to say

Comment: No, package and pip install does not answer the question. We are not talking about packaging, the question was precisely about how to import a file from a different location

Comment: Of course you are right that packaging properly is the way to go if you intend to publish a piece of software. But that doesn't seem to be op's goal. There is super secret stuff in the file... :-D